# How to inject an object using Microsoft Unity framework with a non-default constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm using Microsoft Unity Framework, along with C# and .Net for DI.

The thing is that now I need  to receive an injected object in the constructor of my class, so I can use it. However, I don't want it to be created with it's default constructor, which is happening now.
Does anyone know how to inject an object with a custom constructor, i.e. where and how do I have to register it?

Comment: It's hard to know what you're asking. You might be asking about object factories, property injection alternatives, overloaded constructors. Have any shiny code?

Comment: Actually I was confusing some concepts. The only thing I need to do is to create an object instance and register it in the DI container. Then the registered object will have all the properties set to what I need and any method that needs it will be able to get it from it's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is the  parameterless ctro unity inject dependencies. You can use [InjectionConstructor]. This tells Unity to use that constructor.

Updated more info for [InjectionConstructor]

http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2008/10/28/specifying-injection-constructor-using-unity-fluent-interface-for-loose-coupling-and-poco/

Comment: `InjectionConstructor` sounds like the way to go...but Unity will choose the constructor with the most parameters as the default and not a parameterless constructor.